# 'I thought', 'I would think', 'I would have thought'

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, expressions, word-usage

I'm going to show you three examples.

 1. A - Have you got any change?
    B - Do I have change? What for?
    A - For the vending machine!
           **I would have thought** that was pretty obvious.
 : I think it's sufficient to just say,
  "**I thought** that was pretty obvious."
  because literally 'I' thought so in the past, which is a simple fact, but now I don't.
  And "**I would think** that as pretty obvious." is possible in the context?
  If so, what are the differences among them?

 2. Let's say there are two kids playing in the garden
 
     and their mum comes out to tell them in for dinner.
     But the kids have gone somewhere, so she starts going around for them.
     In some minutes, she finds the two and says.
     "**I would have known.**"
     Why does she talk like that? What's the nuance?
      I think it will do to say,
    "**I knew** you would be here."
      I wonder if "**I would know**" is a possible subsitute for the highlighted sentence.
      If it could be, what are the differences among the three?

 3. A - Was the party great?
     B - I **don't / wouldn't know**. I wasn't there.
 : I think if B goes for "I don't know",
   it will mean he's just saying the plain fact that he wasn't there.
  What if B replies, "I wouldn't know"?
  What's the difference?
   And is "**I wouldn't have known**" possible here?
   If so, what are the differences?

I hear '**would do / would have done**' structure is closely related to a hypothetical if,
but I can't seem to figure it out.
I was guessing 'would have done' might mean speculating about the past,
I've come to think it can't explain 'would do' option.

 Help me out with this.
 Thank you all.

Comment: The second example doesn't make sense. Seems like "I should have known" would make more sense in that case.

Comment: As @fuandon says, the second example is just plain *wrong*. In the other two, using the past "conditional" form slightly "distances" the speaker from the the context, which makes it more formal. In principle it also makes the utterance less "blunt" to the person addressed, but in fact in example #1 the net effect is to "elevate" the speaker, making him seem even more condescending to the addressee. Effectively it's *"I haven't **actually** thought about this because it's too trivial for me to bother with - but if I **did**, this is what I **would** think"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you! Is your explanation true for 'would have done' structure? I wonder if 'would have done' is more 'polite' or 'distant' than 'would do'. If it is, 'would have done' has nothing to do with the past?

Comment: The second example is actually as fine as the others. Here, *would* expresses that the kids notoriously disappear to that place just before dinner time: "I *would* have known that you are here, because you *will* always come here just when I'm about to call you."

Comment: If the mother says "I *should* have known that you are here" as fuandon proposes, that implies that she didn't actually know it. The sense of exasperation is also expressed, though in a different context there need not be any such connotation.

Comment: @Hans Adler: I think you are very mistaken. Sure, Anglophones are pretty sloppy about tenses, but I can't imagine even some oddball dialectal speaker saying *"I should have known that you **are** here"* - it would always be wrong (s/b *"...that you **were** here"*). OP's example #2 seems vanishingly unlikely to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't get your point: "I should have known you were here" - You were here (may not be here any longer), and I should have known that. "I should have known you'd be here" - Once I came here, you were here and I found you. I should have known that in advance. "I should have known you are here" - You have been here during all times relevant to the sentence (from when I did the thinking until now that I found you), and I should have known that.

Comment: After a quick corpus search: Looks like you are right, after all. Instances of "knew that" + present tense are generally in letters or texts of low quality, and in the better ones *knew* isn't even past tense.

Comment: @Hans: Presumably you're not a native speaker. The form *"I **should have known** [something]"* is effectively an idiom meaning *[something] is typical/predictable/just what I'd expect*. It's not really amenable to semantic analysis on the lines of *why "should" rather than "would"?*, because native speakers don't really think about that - they invariably just use the form they've heard all their lives.

Comment: The Cambridge Grammar doesn't mention *should have known* (or *should know*) as a special case, it's not the kind of thing they would simply leave to dictionaries, and it has at least one perfectly straightforward analysis anyway. The only problem with semantic analysis is that for everything involving *would* or *should* there are numerous possible analyses from which one needs to choose one. Which one is correct depends on the period, the speaker's socialisatoin, and sometimes even on which authority if any the speaker is following.

Comment: Analysis would be easier if all native speakers followed the process you are describing. But too many, especially copy editors, are influenced by faulty prescriptive literature.

Comment: Of course the obvious analysis of *should have known* results precisely in what you say it means. The path is like this: I know -> I knew -> I should have known. The only thing remarkable here is that we must skip *I shall have known* because it's no longer current in the required sense. (Formerly, the last step would have been taking the preterite of *shall*.)

Comment: Seems Hans isn't familiar with the use of *should have known* here. It means something is so easy to predict that one doesn't need to even think about it earlier. BTW, when one states his opinion with "I would have thought that..", does it always imply arrogance, surprise or contempt rather than a 'real' softened tone? We should always avoid using this construct if we just want to make opinions tentative? @FumbleFingers

Comment: @Kinzle: Saying *I would have thought [that] X* implies there must be some reason why you didn't just say *I **think** X*. Common reasons include arrogance/contempt (the issue is too trivial/obvious for me to have actually bothered thinking about it), and surprise (I don't think it, since what you've just said belies/undermines X). If you don't want either of those connotations (you just want to advance a tentative thought among "peers") it would probably be better to avoid the "(contra-) conditional" ***would*** completely. ***I am inclined to think that***, anyway.

Comment: Oops, I've been using *I would think* for quite a time; seems I'll have to drop the habit. I wish I didn't cause any misunderstanding. Is *I tend to think* also a good choice? @FumbleFingers

Comment: @Kinzle: I ***suspect*** there are many ways to advance a *tentative* idea without using auxiliary verbs. ***Feasibly*** you could forget about loading it all on the choice of verb (***perhaps*** :)

Comment: I like the way you explain things. Always explanations within a explanation. :) @FumbleFingers

Answer (score 2):

1. I’m sure all of these variations are commonly used and understood to mean roughly the same thing. “I would have thought…” essentially means “I believe you should have understood what I meant,” or “that should be obvious.” “I thought that was obvious” is a simple declaration that sounds more like the speaker actually gave the matter some thought.
2. “I should [not “would”] have known,” means that she realizes, after finding the boys, that she should have expected to find them where she did. “I knew you would be here” is similar, but means that she went straight to wherever she found the boys based on her knowledge of their habits. Both phrases might imply some disapproval of their being there.
   “I would know” (or “I should know”) is not a possible substitute for your sentence. As a complete clause, it’s more like “you can take my word for it,” or “take it from me,” implying some experience of a situation, often said ruefully or with a little chagrin.
3. “I don’t/wouldn’t know”: There wouldn’t be much reason to answer “I don’t know”; it’s more direct to just say that you weren’t there. “I wouldn’t know” might be employed where there’s some displeasure, like if B thought he should have been invited to the party but wasn’t. The “would” in “I wouldn’t know” is present tense; “I wouldn’t have known” is not possible here because it puts it in the past tense.

Answer (score 0):

"I would think" and "I would have thought" are instances of the common use of the conditional to soften assertions.  This can be useful in establishing plausible deniability or saving face in case the assertion proves to be incorrect.  It can also help reduce the harshness of a correction (that is, saying "no, three squared is nine" is blunt and might offend, but "I would have thought that three squared is nine." is less blunt and more likely to be accepted.)

Stephen Pinker touches on this some of his writing, and in this talk he discusses how it is related to people's managing their relationships with one another: http://www.ted.com/talks/steven_pinker_on_language_and_thought