# "Science wouldn't have thought so, but she is." Why the past tense?

Tags: tenses

Here's a quote from a TV show:

> "How's your mother?"
> "She's meaner."
> "Is that even possible?"
> "Science wouldn't have thought so, but she is."

It just runs naturally off the tongue, doesn't it?

But why the past tense? Why does "Science wouldn't think so" sound wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['I thought', 'I would think', 'I would have thought'.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187936/i-thought-i-would-think-i-would-have-thought) Also [“I would think” vs “I would have thought”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94448/i-would-think-vs-i-would-have-thought) over on English Language Learners, where this question belongs.

Comment: The (present) conditional perfect is used because until this moment (*now*), no one thought it was possible for that person to be meaner in the future but “science”, which stands for anyone who personally knows this mother, has been proved wrong.

Comment: The subject "science" strikes me as a bit odd here, but [per this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=You+would+have+thought+so%2CYou+would+think+so&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CYou%20would%20have%20thought%20so%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CYou%20would%20think%20so%3B%2Cc0), ***You would have thought so*** has always been around alongside ***You would think so***. And I'd say that in [almost?] every case, they're ***completely interchangeable.*** And the negation in the current example makes no difference to the preferred *syntax*.

Comment: ...and although it's still a "minority" usage, the Perfect form [puts up a better showing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27d+have+thought+so%2CI%27d+think+so&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20%27d%20have%20thought%20so%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20%27d%20think%20so%3B%2Cc0) in a colloquial abbreviated context, with ***I*** as the subject, when comparing ***I'd have thought so*** against ***I'd think so***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: 1. No. There are some long meandering attempts to answer the question (which is not the same question, but that's a side matter), but no definitive answer. 2. It is more complicated than it seems.

Comment: I don't think it's at all "complicated". *Semantically*, switching from Simple Present to Present Perfect for such conditional hypothetical assertions *(I would think, I would have thought)* makes absolutely no difference, since (theoretically) you ***aren't*** thinking [whatever], ***nor did you***. English only really has two tenses (Present, and "Non-Present"), but once you've made the context hypothetical even that distinction becomes a bit irrelevant. All that matters is the Perfect is more "distant" from "here and now", so it's often seen as more "detached" and/or "deferential".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Uh ... I'd have to disagree with the "English only really has two tenses" part: I may understand the sentiment, but it does strike me as aesthetically wrong. But, generally speaking, you've just given me a pretty good answer, and I very much doubt it (the answer) would be understood, much less fully appreciated, at ELL.

Comment: When one is trying to judge how natural a usage in a sentence sounds by ear (it can only _be judged_ by some ear/s or other), when there are complicating factors (here the odd personification of _science_ pointed out by FF) the task becomes near impossible. // Here, 'You wouldn't think so' is quite acceptable, but 'You wouldn't have thought so' is more usual after the query 'Is that even possible?' _As stated eloquently by djna in the ELL thread already mentioned_ (Though I'd say this is one that belongs properly on ELU.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Yes, well, my sentiments exactly, but I guess I was looking for a formal explanation sprinkled with some arcane terminology.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I think the Perfect might be less likely in the *exact* current context, which kinda suggests there should be some *reason* for this. But if I imagine the conversation *starting* with *I wouldn't have thought it possible, but my mother continues to get meaner with every passing day*, the Perfect seems far more natural. Perhaps this is something to do with how "close or distant" the very *idea* of the hypothetical "non-thought" is from the current conversation (it's *very* distant if the conversation hasn't even *started* yet! :)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Excellent points all, thank you.

Comment: @FF 'You wouldn't have thought so' adds a further layer of hedging to 'You wouldn't think so' (rather didactic) (with 'Of course not' having 'Punch me' as a subtext). But _science_ hardly needs/merits protective politeness devices. But again,  'It just runs naturally off the tongue' apparently isn't being used in a way exactly synonymous with 'it sounds pleasing to the ear'. I'd want 'It may seem to defy science, but ...' or better. // But, example apart, the question is a good one (though _is_ probably a duplicate. Pity (for ELU) the best answer is on the other channel.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I would have thought so, but a number of people already want it closed and/or migrated. Since I got my answer, I might as well delete it, right? And we can all go back to "two nouns for “do it now” and “delay it to the future," or whatever the latest proper and legitimate "question" might be here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, Ricky: I've [added my own answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/271986/126) to the ELL version of the question, if you're interested.

Comment: btw Ricky - I don't think you should *delete* your question, whatever happens. Even if all except one version of a question are closed as duplicates, those closed questions help future visitors (or sharp-eyed closevoters! :) find *pre-existing* versions of the new question.

Comment: I've asked modistration at ELL if there's a chance of sharing the best answer there (prior to FF's, at least: must look) or even transferring it this way. I feel rather guilty, trying to loot their works of art.